# Converting a hierarchy of off-site web-links to Word-Press

Tags: links, hierarchical

I'm looking at converting several PHP-Fusion sites to WordPress.  I'm wondering how to convert a page like this: http://biztalk-training.com/weblinks.php.  Is there a plug-in for links that will create a similar type page.  Each link can have an abstract and the URL, and with PHP-Fusion it even tracks which links get clicked, but I can do without the counts or use Google-Analytics for that.

Comment: Can I assume you have access to the MySQL database powering PHP-Fusion?

Comment: Yes, I could write a PHP, VBScript, Python or whatever to extract the data, the question is how to present it in Wordpress (and then how to get it into WordPress). I think I can use the extended RSS import/export "custom pages" and articles of PHP-Fusion. I might start a little open-source project for this as I recently did for a conversion from Phatnotes to Evernote.

Comment: The PHP-Fusion "side panels" are another interesting feature I need to study-up more in WordPress. Some of them are like mini-pages that are stored in "side panels", and then you can re-arrange them to appear anywhere on the left or right, maybe like the widgets in WP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found Link Library to be pretty flexible.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/link-library/

Comment: Looks good, I'll give it a try later this week.